# How do I ensure that a celery task is run serially on a worker?

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have a celery task that makes a subprocess call that can only be run parallel system-wide.  While I figure out a better solution, I need to be able to execute tasks that run serially on a single worker.

I know I could create a table to track which server is currently running the task, and wait for that to finish before future tasks are run, but it seems like there must be a better way.  I've looked pretty extensively into the celery documentation, and briefly at the rabbitmq documentation to no avail.

Has anyone out there come up with an elegant solution to this problem that hooks into some hidden features of the aforementioned technologies?

Comment: Can you clarify your setup a bit? You have multiple servers, each running a single celery worker, but you don't want them executing in parallel- is that correct? Do you have just one rabbitmq server running?

Comment: @dgel: One rabbitmq server, with multiple workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you setup a [database cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#database-caching) in django that uses a database common to all servers you could implement this [celery cookbook solution for executing one task at time](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time). Instead of using a variable `lock_id`, just use a constant.

In the event that the lock is not available to the worker executing the task, call [retry](http://celery.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) to put the task back into the queue.

Comment: I figured this was what I'd have to do.  Do you happen to know how to get a unique identifier for the worker within the task?

Comment: @sdolan: Hmm... Unfortunately not.